# Artisan CronJob - There are no commands defined in the "xyz" namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron

I am having a bit of a strange problem with an artisan command I have setup.

The command is:

```
cd /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/ && /usr/bin/php-5.4 artisan property:import
```

This command works perfectly when run via ssh or on a local machine, but fails to run when set as a CronJob and returns the following error in the Laravel log file.

```
[2014-06-17 13:50:06] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "property" namespace.' in /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:514

Stack trace:
#0 /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(548): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('property')
#1 /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(188): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('property:import')
#2 /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /var/sites/p/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/artisan(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#4 {main} [] []
```

I am rather stuck and have no idea why the "property" namespace would not be found when being run as a cron. When running the exact same command via ssh, it works perfectly, when running on a local machine, it works perfectly.

Would there be anything in artisan that is causing it not to load the *app/start/artisan.php* file when run as a cronjob at all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any further details, let me know and I will provide what I can.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time of checking and speaking with the hosting provider it turned out that running `/usr/bin/php-5.4` was running the cgi version of php, changing this to `/usr/bin/php-5.4-cli` fixed the issue.

This would of course very depending on your hosting providers setup.